# Consuming Service From Consul in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, consul

we've setup a consul cluster with a couple of services on, and that's working fine. My question is what is the best way to discover the service in my winforms app.

I can connect to the cluster fine using one of the clusters IP address, and see the services, but my question is what is the best way to actually connect to the cluster to discover the services?

Its seems a bit naff to have to specify an IP of one of the servers in the cluster, what if that server is down?

I guess we could maybe use a DNS round-robin address, or loop over pre-defined servers but again that doesn't seem amazing.

How are other people doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, some kind of Load Balancer is used to access the cluster with single IP-address and port. For example, [HAProxy](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html). In that case, balancer cares of your request to reach active server instance and the only address you need is balancer's address. But for sure, in most cases, this will need some extra resources.

Comment: i guess that's an option, but still seems a bit resource and config heavy